# tsfknn:: extracting autoplot predictions into a table

Tags: r, plot, rstudio

In the tsfknn package, there is the autoplot function. It plots a prediction and the nearest neighbors used in the prediction. The predicted values are in red, and the values from data are in black. Is there a way to extract the red points into a dataframe?

Example:

```
# prepping data
data <- as.data.frame(seq(as.Date('2017/04/01'), as.Date('2019/11/01'), by="day"))
data <- rlang::set_names(data, "Date")
data[, "Year"] <- format(data[,"Date"], "%Y")
data[, "Month"] <- format(data[,"Date"], "%m")
data[, "Quantity"] <- sample(100, size = nrow(data), replace = TRUE)
monthly <- dplyr::group_by(data, Year, Month)
monthly <- summarise(monthly, sum(Quantity))
monthly <- set_names(monthly, c("Year", "Month", "Quantity"))
```

```
# ts the data
ts.example <- ts(data = monthly$Quantity, start = c(2017,4), frequency = 12)
# quarterly ts 
quarterly <- aggregate(ts.example, nfrequency = 4)/3
```

```
# knn part
quarterly.knn <- knn_forecasting(quarterly, h = 4, lags = 1:4, k = 3, msas = "MIMO")
```

```
# plotting the predictions
autoplot(quarterly.knn, highlight = "none", faceting = TRUE)
```

I would like to know what exactly are those prediction values.

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

```
library(tsfknn)
f <- knn_forecasting(AirPassengers, h = 10) # the function returns a list
print(f$prediction) # the prediction component contains the prediction
```

Comment: Please add this along the answer and not as a comment.

Comment: While this code may resolve the OP's issue, it is best to include an explanation as to how your code addresses the OP's issue. In this way, future visitors can learn from your post, and apply it to their own code. SO is not a coding service, but a resource for knowledge. Also, high quality, complete answers are more likely to be upvoted. These features, along with the requirement that all posts are self-contained, are some of the strengths of SO as a platform, that differentiates it from forums. You can edit to add additional info &/or to supplement your explanations with source documentation.